# How to join the three different code boxes from jsfiddle.net into a HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to create a web site just with a jsfiddle.net application.

I'd like to know how to join the three different code boxes from jsfiddle.net into a HTML page.

The HTML code for my page is

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        ***CSS box***
        </style>
</head>
    <body>
    ***HTML box***

        <script language="JavaScript"  type="text/javascript">
        ***Javascript box***
        </script>   
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that I can't make it work

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much.

Comment: "The problem is that I can't make it work" ...and what did you try, that isn't working? What's going wrong with what you're trying?

Comment: jsFiddle isn't for developing websites, it's for testing code.

Comment: Your HTML code above is valid (assuming you replace `***CSS box***` etc. with appropriate code from your jsfiddle). As noted earlier, ksfiddle is only used to test code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy and paste the respective sections in a new HTML file on say your desktop.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        // CSS Content
        </style>
</head>
    <body>
    <!-- some html elements -->

        <script language="JavaScript"  type="text/javascript">
            // more js here.
        </script>   
    </body>
</html>
```

And then link in any dependencies such as jQuery within your head element.

Comment: I did exactly as it is above for a very nice code I found for one embed YouTube channel. The code for YouTube channel is found here http://jsfiddle.net/SimoneGianni/NmvA9/   | I used that code with the above HTML code to join everything together on a HTML page but it is not working... may you kindly help? Thanks a lot...

Comment: Thank you a lot. It is working. It was a problem with jQuery dependencies. Thank you